# How to change content type of Amazon S3 Objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The objects in my Amazon S3 bucket are all of the content type `application/octet-stream`. Some of these objects are PDFs, sometimes images like `JPG`, `GIF`, `PNG`. How can I change the content type of these objects to `images/jpeg`, `application/pdf` etc.?

Can it be done in batch through the Amazon Console?

Can I use the command line?

Or maybe through PHP?

Answer (score 82):

This is how you can set `Content-Type` for all files of type ***.png**

```
aws s3 cp \
       s3://BUCKET-NAME/ \
       s3://BUCKET-NAME/ \
       --exclude '*' \
       --include '*.png' \
       --no-guess-mime-type \
       --content-type="image/png" \
       --metadata-directive="REPLACE" \
       --recursive
```

Comment: Thanks! Was in the middle of having to write a whole script to do just this

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. However, when running in Windows AWS CLI, please be sure to remove the quotes from `--exclude` and `--include` option values, as they will be ignored - this caused the CLI to just copy all the files in my S3 regardless of their extension. Once I did `--exclude * --include *.png` it worked great.

Comment: Here is the official document: "If REPLACE is used, the copied object will only have the metadata values that were specified by the CLI command. Note that if you are using any of the following parameters: --content-type, content-language, --content-encoding, --content-disposition, --cache-control, or --expires, you will need to specify --metadata-directive REPLACE for non-multipart copies if you want the copied objects to have the specified metadata values." ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html )

Comment: This does not changes the content type of S3 object versions. Please suggest.

Answer (score 8):

You can use AWS sdk (php or other) I'll show how it works using CLI. To change content type on S3 given object, you need to copy this object and update the metadata information using the `REPLACE` tag so it copies to itself, you can achieve that using http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/copy-object.html

```
aws s3api copy-object --bucket <bucket_name> \
    --content-type "images/jpeg" \
    --copy-source <bucket_name>/path/to/images.jpeg \
    --key path/to/images.jpeg \
    --metadata-directive "REPLACE"
```

Comment: Cool, but first I somehow need to select all objects with a certain extension like .jpg

Answer (score 7):

```
aws s3 ls \
  s3://<YOUR_BUCKET> --recursive | 
  awk '{print substr($0, index($0, $4))}' | 
  grep <FILE_EXTENSTION> | 
  while read -r line; do \
    aws s3api copy-object \
      --bucket <YOUR_BUCKET> \
      --acl "<ACL_POLICY_IF_NEEDED>" \
      --content-type "<REQUIRED_CONTENT_TYPE>" \
      --copy-source "<YOUR_BUCKET>/$line" \
      --key "$line" --metadata-directive "REPLACE"; \
  done
```

This will do the trick. Breaking down the commands:

- `aws s3 ls s3://<YOUR_BUCKET> --recursive` => This lists all files in your bucket
- `awk '{print substr($0, index($0, $4))}'`  => This will remove extra information like date and just give you all list of keys
- `grep <FILE_EXTENSTION>` => This will filter the extension(say pdf/jpg) for which you want to update the content-type
- `while read -r line; do aws s3api copy-object --bucket <YOUR_BUCKET> --acl "<ACL_POLICY_IF_NEEDED>" --content-type "<REQUIRED_CONTENT_TYPE>" --copy-source "<YOUR_BUCKET>/$line" --key "$line" --metadata-directive "REPLACE"; done`  => This will replace all the filtered files in your bucket with the content-type you specify

Comment: Is there a way to not show the output and having to exit every update?

Comment: could redirect copy-object command to /dev/null