# How to apply content type to Amazon S3 objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Using `CLI` (not `s3cmd`) to manage Amazon S3, how can I select all objects with extension `.pdf` and apply the content type `application/pdf`?

This is what I came up with so far:

```
aws s3 sync s3://${BUCKET_NAME} s3://${BUCKET_NAME}
--dryrun
--exclude '*'
--include '*.pdf'
--no-guess-mime-type
--content-type application/pdf
```

Using the `--debug` parameter I found out about this error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the CopyObject operation:
This copy request is illegal because it is trying to copy an object to itself
without changing the object's metadata, storage class,
website redirect location or encryption attributes.
```

Comment: Can you try your command with no option. Then add option one by one to see when it fails ?

Comment: @Sylwit I used the --debug parameter, found the error and updated the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58041788/4134265 Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Try changing metadata directly:

```
aws s3 sync s3://${BUCKET_NAME} s3://${BUCKET_NAME}
--dryrun
--exclude '*'
--include '*.pdf'
--no-guess-mime-type
--metadata Content-Type=application/pdf
```