# python - Boto3 Put Forcing Download for PNG

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am uploading `png` images to a public S3 bucket.  However, when I access the images in my browser, instead of displaying inline, they automatically download.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550816/aws-content-type-settings-in-s3-using-boto3/40310420), I wrote the following code.

```
with open(new_img_path, "rb") as f:
    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=s3_img_path, Body=f, ContentType="image/png")
```

When I view the file uploaded, it still forces me to download it.

The way I can fix that problem is by running the `CLI` command found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46932483/1723469).

```
aws s3 cp \                                              
                s3://bucket/ \
                s3://bucket/ \
                --exclude '*' \
                --include '*.png' \
                --no-guess-mime-type \
                --content-type="image/png" \
                --metadata-directive="REPLACE" \
                --recursive
```

After running those commands it works just fine.  The problem is, I don't want to have to use the `CLI` to fix something that is being done programmatically.

For reference, here are screenshots of the metadata:

- [Mug_left.png metadata screenshot - working properly](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0h0eio1qpsgyrri/Screen%20Shot%202020-04-01%20at%2011.04.39%20AM.png?dl=0)
- [christopher.png metadata screenshot - not working](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sz7coe9izehjsg8/Screen%20Shot%202020-04-01%20at%2011.04.58%20AM.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  The `ACL` argument wasn't set to `public-read`.

Here is the working code, formatted for readability:

```
with open(new_img_path, "rb") as f:
    s3.put_object(
        Bucket=bucket,
        Key=s3_img_path,
        Body=f,
        ContentType="image/png",
        ACL="public-read"
    )
```